# proper way to create a typescript object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been searching around, but I don't see the answer I'm looking for. Please let me know if my question is duplicated.

I'm trying to create an object in typescript which contains attributes that are custom types.

The problem is my server provides the object with urls. I'm not sure how to deal with the mapping. Please excuse me if I'm not explaining this well. I'm kind of new to all these. BTW I'm using Angular and Typescript

Here is an example. The object is like:

```
export class Contact { 
    name : string;
    address : {
        street : string;
        city : string;
    }
}
```

But, the json retrieved from my server is like:

```
{
    "name" : "firstname lastname",
    "address" : "http://localhost:5000/contacts/001"
}
```

If I use the address url I should get the address in json format.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It seems you miss a lot of basic knowledge about what you're doing and what you want to do. There's not really a way to give a *good* answer to your problem.

Comment: you mean the url is another http call to get back the "address" information?

Comment: @lexith You are right, I have never done any front end stuff. I pretty much went through that one example on angular.io and trying to create a CRUD application.

Comment: @Ayyash Yes, the url will be used to call http get to retrieve the "address" information in json format

Comment: Do you have control over what the server provides? Can you get the address on the server instead of a trip back from client?

Comment: @Ayyash, I do. I can get the address as a json instead of url, but there are other models that have complex relationships. For example, a student contains classes  and a class contains students. student.to_json() will trigger class.to_json(), which calls student.to_json() again; it becomes an infinite loop.

Comment: This is basically object oriented design, you have to design your objects and create methods just like you do i C# or Java or any other language, but do get everything you need from the server first, not urls that trigger extra calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume your question about how to map server retrieved data to local typescript objects, one way of doing it is create a static method in class to return a New Instance of the class, it takes an object of type "any" and returns an object after mapping all properties. Use that method after http request comes back, or after subscription, depends on your setup.

```
export class Address {
   constructor(public name:string, description: string){
    }
   public static NewInstance(address: any){
      //map here
      return new Address(address.db_name, address.address);
   }
}
export class Student {
    constructor(
        public name : string,
        public classes: StudentClass[],
        public address: Address
    ){

    }
     public static NewInstance(student: any){
         let studentclasses = student.classes.map(n => StudentClass.NewInstance(n));
         return new Student(student.firstname+' ' + student.lastname, studentclasses, Address.NewInstance(student.addresss));
    }

}
export class StudentClass {
   constructor(public: name: string);
   public static NewInstance(studentclass: any){
        return new StudentClass(studentclass.namefromdb);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

parse the json that you have retrieved from server then assign it to your properties like below

```
...
.subscribe(
data => {
  this.name = data.name
  this.address = data.adress
})
```

**Note** that a good practice is to define a separate service for making request to server

Comment: Thanks for you response! So you mean after I get the response from the http call back, I should make another http call with the url to get the address?

Comment: if you want to get data from address then you should do that